# C++ sort code to python sorted

Tags: python, c++, sorting

I am trying to convert below C++ code to python expecially the sorting logic using sorted function but how can I pass two values in key parameter of sorted function

```
//vector<string> str contains some values
sort(str.begin(), str.end(), compareNum);

bool compareNum(string a, string b) {
   return a + b > b + a;
}
```

How to convert above code using sorted function in python

Comment: You can't. Find another way.

Comment: So do you mean there is no way to compare to elements in a list while sorting in python using standard functions (like sorted) ??

Comment: It was removed a few versions ago.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the `key` parameter but the `cmp` parameter. https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_the_cmp_Parameter

Comment: python3 got rid of the `cmp` parameter. so if you want your python2 code to be python3 compatible convert your `cmp` function via `functools.cmp_to_key` (don't worry the end result is the same).